# Question about convex combination of characteristic functions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, characteristic-functions

Suppose 
\begin{align}
f(t)=\alpha g(t)+(1-\alpha) h(t) 
\end{align}
for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$ and for some $\alpha \in (0,1)$.

Suppose that $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ are characteristic function.  Does this imply that $h(t)$ is also a chararacteristic function?

Thank you.

Comment: $f$ is a convex combination of $g$ and $h$. So if $g$ and $h$ are characteristic functions, $f$ is also a characteristic functions (consider the mixture distribution). But $h$ is not a convex combination of $f$ and $g$ so $f$ and $g$ are characteristic functions do not imply $h$ is.

Comment: @BGM I am not sure that I follow your proof. Any counter examples you have in mind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly recall the valid statement:
If $F_1$ and $F_2$ are some distributions with characteristic functions $g(t)$ and $h(t)$, then $F=\alpha F_1+(1-\alpha)F_2$ is their mixture with characteristic function 
\begin{align}
f(t)=\alpha g(t)+(1-\alpha) h(t). 
\end{align}
Take $\alpha=0{,}5$ for simplicity. Then the equality $F=\alpha F_1+(1-\alpha)F_2$ turns to $2F=F_1+F_2$.

If conversely we take some distributions $F$ and $F_1$, the difference $F_2=2F-F_1$ is not obliged to be some distribution. Say, we can take distribution $F$ degenerate at $1$, and $F_1$ degenerate at $0$, and the difference $F_2=2F-F_1$ is not a distribution at all.

Return to characteristic functions. CF for $F$ equals $f(t)=e^{it}$, CF for $F_1$ is $g(t)=1$. The second summand $h(t)$ in the equality
$$e^{it}=\frac12 \cdot 1 + \frac12 \cdot h(t)$$
is $h(t)=2e^{it}-1$. This is not CF since the absolute value of this function can be greater than $1$.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know what happens if we restrict the question to real and symmetric characteristic functions?

Comment: @Boby Nothing will change. You can find a suitable example.